# QUERY in REST URI in Workbench?

Tags: rest-api, query, rest

I have been trying to query the Lookup object field in workbench Rest Explorer.  Please help me on how to query the Lookup Object Field.

/services/data/v20.0/query?q=SELECT Data_Source__c,Name,Invoice_Date__c, Claim__r.Prior__r.Name FROM Invoice__c

I am getting invalid query whenever I trying to get field for Lookup relationship..
   looupkupobjectField__r.Fieldname... and can i traverse more  like looupkupobjectField__r. looupkupobjectField__rFieldname

Please help . Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked for the correct relationship names? Good to check with the WSDL

Comment: check this relation Claim__r.Prior__r.Name .To check this go to validation or formulae and pick the fields,it shows the relation how they are mapped.

Comment: Are you remembering the `__c` on the end of the field name - i.e. `looupkupobject.Field__r.Fieldname__c`

Comment: I have checked a checkbox in workbench setting.  "Allows SOQL Parent Relationship Queries" and it started working...

Comment: Use + symbols instead of space in your query

Answer (score 0):

In the query replace the space with '+' symbol. like this
query?q=SELECT+Id,Name+FROM+USER